# Jenkins won't verify https with jks keystore

Tags: docker, ssl, jenkins, ssl-certificate, keystore

I'm setting up a Jenkins instance inside of Docker and I'm wanting to enable https. I have keystore that contains 2 entries

```
Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 2 entries

*.example.com, Jul 13, 2020, PrivateKeyEntry, 
Certificate fingerprint (SHA-256): <finger print>
*.example.com (geotrust rsa ca 2018), Jul 13, 2020, trustedCertEntry, 
Certificate fingerprint (SHA-256): <finger print>
```

In my Dockerfile I have the following

```
RUN mkdir -p /etc/jenkins
COPY certs/stkeystore /etc/jenkins/keystore
RUN chown -R jenkins: /etc/jenkins \
    && chmod 700 /etc/jenkins \
    && chmod 600 /etc/jenkins/keystore
EXPOSE 8443
```

My compose file looks like this

```yaml
version: "3.3"

services:
  jenkins:
    build: services/jenkins
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home
      - docker_certs:/certs/client
    ports:
      - "8443:8443"
      - "3268:3268"
      - "50000:50000"
    environment:
      DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2376
      DOCKER_CERT_PATH: /certs/client
      DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY: 1
      JENKINS_OPTS: --httpPort=-1 --httpsPort=8443 --httpsKeyStore=/etc/jenkins/keystore --httpsKeyStorePassword=changeit
```

Running `docker-compose up jenkins` and everything starts up fine except that when I access jenkins.example.com:8443 I get the following

[image]

If I try and curl the url I get

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

The cert isn't self signed though? it says it's signed by a CA in the keytool list

Comment: With `curl` or in the Browser did you check whether the correct certificate is returned? Or you can use `openssl` as well.

Comment: Also, your path doesn't seem to point to a keystore `--httpsKeyStore=/etc/jenkins/keystore`.  The path should point to a JKS e.g:  `/etc/jenkins/keystore/store.jks`

Comment: @ycr The entry I'm getting is the keypair not the cert, is that correct? also the path to the keystore is right, it doesn't have file extension but it is in jks format

Comment: In the client side(Browser/Curl) you should be getting the certificate.

Comment: @ycr well it's not, it's getting `*.example.com` not `*.example.com (geotrust rsa ca 2018)`. How can I fix that? deleting the keypair entry breaks it and I'm not able to load anything

Comment: In your Keytool listing, the first entry is the Private key that will be used to initiate the SSL connection. The private key will have its corresponding certificate which will be sent to the client when initiating the SSL handshake. The second entry is an Entry for a trusted certificate.  Can you list the steps you followed to create the ketstore? How did you get the CA signed cert?

Comment: @ycr that's how I have the cert ordered but it seems to be sending the private key instead of the cert. I'm not sure how we got the cert, it was the one I was told to use and I know we've used it before to setup a jira instance.